# .some() function using async and await always returning true

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a JavaScript class with some `async` functions inside.

If there is a number greater than 10 in this array I expect the [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function to return true, but if the array contains no numbers larger than 10 I expect it to return false.

The issue I'm having is that the function call is always returning `true` whether or not there is a number greater than 10 in the array.

```
class Blah {
    async doStuff() {
        const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
        const asyncResult = await nums.some(async num => {
            if (num > 10) {
                const allowed = await this.isAllowed(num);
                if (allowed) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });

        console.log(asyncResult);
    }

    async isAllowed(num) {
        console.log(`${num} is in the array`);
        return true;
    }
}

const b = new Blah();
b.doStuff(); // This return true but it should be returning false
```

This currently returns `true` but as you can see the array does not have a number larger than `10`

If I remove the `async` from inside the `.some()` function then it seems to work, but that function needs to be `async` because I need to `await` on the `this.isAllowed` function call and that is also an `async` function.

Comment: An `async` function returns a promise, which is truth-y, so `.some` will always pass. If you need to resolve a bunch of promises in parallel, use `Promise.all`. Or use a vanilla `for of` loop if you want to resolve them in series.

Comment: I sort of get that - I guess where would I put the `Promise.all` in the code above? @jonrsharpe

Comment: `const asyncResult = await Promise.all( /* array of promises */ )`. *Then* you can do `asyncResult.some( /* predicate */ )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem:

Your `some` handler is an `async` function. Async functions **always** return promises, which are considered truthy. E.g. `!!new Promise(() => {}) === true`.

The solution:

Instead, you could use `Promise.all`. Iterate through each num, if any pass your condition, resolve true the return promise. If `Promise.all` completes (i.e., you've checked all nums) and the returned promise hasn't already been resolved (i.e. none of the nums passed your condition), then resolve false (or reject) your return promise.

```js
class Blah {
  doStuff(nums) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let promises = nums.map(async num => {
        if (num > 10 && await this.isAllowed(num))
          resolve(true);
      });
      Promise.all(promises).then(() => resolve(false));
    });
  }

  async isAllowed(num) {
    console.log(`${num} is in the array`);
    return true;
  }
}

const b = new Blah();

b.doStuff([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).then(value => console.log(value));

b.doStuff([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 20]).then(value => console.log(value));
```

Comment: Tried this method and all I got was `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: true is not iterable`

Comment: Fixed,  I'd forgotten to wrap the `resolve(false)` in a lambda. give it another try. I've also made nums a param just so the snippet will showcase a true and false example.

Answer (score 0):

`.some` is synchronous. When your function return a promise (as all asynchronous functions do), `.some` treats this as a truthy value. Thus, the result is true.

If you want to let all the promises resolve, and then check the results, you can do that like this:

```
async doStuff() {
  const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  const promises = nums.map(async num => {
    if (num > 10) {
      const allowed = await this.isAllowed(num);
      if (allowed) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  });
  const areAllowed = await Promise.all(promises);
  const result = areAllowed.some(val => val);
  console.log(result);
}
```

If these are potentially long running promises and you want to be able to bail out as soon as any one of them resolves to true, you can do that something like this:

```
async doStuff() {
  const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  const result = await new Promise(resolve => {
    let notAllowedCount = 0;
    nums.forEach(async num => {
      if (num > 10) {
        const allowed = await this.isAllowed(num);
        if (allowed) {
          // Found one that is allowed. Immediately resolve the outer promise
          resolve(true);
          return;
        }
      }
      // This one isn't allowed
      notAllowedCount++;
      if (notAllowedCount === nums.length) {
        // If we've reached the end, resolve to false. This will only happen
        //    if none of the earlier ones resolved it to true.
        resolve(false);
      }
    });
  });

  console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this should help (run code snippet):

```js
const isLGTen = async (n) => {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  
  return n > 10;
}


const someLGTen = nums => Promise
  .all(nums.map(isLGTen))
  .then(result => result.some(bool => bool));


(async () => {
  const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11];

  console.log(
    `is some of "${data}" > "10"?`, 
    await someLGTen(data),
  );
})()
```