# array.some() returns unexpected true in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this lines of code

```
const countryIds = intersectingBbox.split(';');
const countryFound = countryIds.some(async (id) => {
     const possibleCountry = await _inBbox(id);
     return _checkPointInPolygonAndDispatch(possibleCountry);
});
```

This `_checkPointInPolygonAndDispatch()` is a rather complicated function, but in the end it returns `true` or `false`. The `some()` runs twice. The first iteration it goes into the block of `_checkPointInPolygonAndDispatch()` where it returns `false`. The second time it goes into the block of `_checkPointInPolygonAndDispatch()` where it returns `false`, and then it breaks the iteration. Logging `countryFound` gives me a `true`. This is unexpected because in this function `_checkPointInPolygonAndDispatch()` it always goes into the block, where it returns `false`. I rewrote the whole thing to this

```
const countryIds = intersectingBbox.split(';');
for (let index = 0; index < countryIds.length; index++) {
    const possibleCountry = await _inBbox(countryIds[index]);
    const countryFound = _checkPointInPolygonAndDispatch(possibleCountry)
    if (countryFound) {
        break;
    }
}
```

And this works as expected.

So I am assuming, I missunderstand `some()`? I thought it runs as long as something evaluates to `true`?!

Comment: `some` doesn't resolve promises.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56171786/some-function-using-async-and-await-always-returning-true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your async function is returning a `Promise` which is truthy. you will have to restructure your code to handle the promises.

Comment: Ah well, that explains it... And I was staring at the code :)